# closed set of closed subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\left(X,\tau\right)$ be a topological space and $M\subseteq X$ be closed and equip with the subspace topology $\tau_M$. I am trying to show that if $A\subseteq M$ is closed in $\tau_M$ then $A$ is closed in $\tau$. However, I've come to a *roadblock*.

Here is my attempt: $A$ is closed in $\tau_M \iff A^c$ is open in $\tau_M \iff \exists U\in\tau: A^c = M\cap U.$ So, carrying out De Morgan gives, $A = M^c\cup U^c$. Clearly, $M^c\in\tau$ however, $U^c\notin\tau$. So, how do am I suppose to conclude that $A$ is open in $\tau$ hence $A^c$ is closed in $\tau$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is closed in $M$, then $M\setminus A$ is open in $M$, and therefore $M\setminus A=M\cap O$, for some $O\in\tau$. So, $A=M\cap O^\complement$. But, since both $M$ and $O^\complement$ are closed subsets of $(X,\tau)$, $M\cap O^\complement$ is also a closed subset of $(X,\tau)$; in other words, $A$ is a closed subset of $(X,\tau)$.